# Solve for $x$ in $\sqrt[4]{57-x}+\sqrt[4]{x+40}=5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations

Solve for $x$ in $$\sqrt[4]{57-x}+\sqrt[4]{x+40}=5$$

i have done in a lengthy way:

By inspection we observe that $x=41$ and $x=-24$ are the solutions

we have

$$\sqrt[4]{57-x}=5-\sqrt[4]{x+40}$$ squaring both sides we get

$$\sqrt{57-x}=25+\sqrt{x+40}-10 \sqrt[4]{x+40}$$ that is

$$\sqrt{57-x}-25=\sqrt{x+40}-10 \sqrt[4]{x+40}$$ again squaring both sides we get

$$682-x-50\sqrt{57-x}=x+40+100\sqrt{x+40}-20(x+40)^{\frac{3}{4}}$$

i got messed up here any better way and just a hint please

Comment: Before you did the last squaring, it would have been better to isolate the fourth root and then square. That way, you only have to deal with square roots afterwards

Comment: MathJax hint:  You can get the fourth root sign with \sqrt[4]{57} which gives $\sqrt[4]{57}$  If you think the four is too small, you can see how to adjust it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49043/nice-looking-p-th-roots) but it takes work.

Comment: "By inspection" you have better skills of inspection than I do!

Comment: @zz20s what you can do is to try all $x$ such that $57-x$ is a forth power and see if the equation equals $5$. You have to try $3$ values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sqrt[4]{57-x}+\sqrt[4]{x+40}=5$$

Let $y=\sqrt[4]{57-x}$, and $z=\sqrt[4]{x+40}$
Then
$$y\ge 0, z \ge 0, y+z=5$$
$$x=57- y^4=z^4-40$$

Thus
$$y^4+ (5-y)^4-97$$
$$=2(y-3)(y-2)(y^2-5y+44)=0$$

Thus $y=2$ or $y=3$, which means $x=41$ or $x=-24$

We are done.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I would recommend you to make the following substitution $a = \sqrt[4]{57 - x}$ and $b = \sqrt[4]{x+40}$. Thus we have $a + b = 5$ and $a^{4} + b^{4} = 57 + 40 = 97$. Therefore:
\begin{align*}
a^{4}+b^{4} & = (a^{2}+b^{2})^{2} - 2a^{2}b^{2} = [(a+b)^{2} - 2ab]^{2} - 2a^{2}b^{2} = (5^{2} - 2ab)^{2} - 2a^{2}b^{2}\\
& = (25 - 2ab)^{2} - 2a^{2}b^{2} = 625 - 100ab + 2a^{2}b^{2} = 97
\end{align*}
Henceforward we shall also agree that $\alpha = a + b$ and $\beta = ab$. According to the last relation, we obtain that $2\beta^{2} - 100\beta + 528 = 0$, whose solutions are $\beta_{1} = 6$ and $\beta_{2} = 44$. After solving the corresponding collection of systems of equations, we obtain the next solution set $S = \{-24,41\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since you found two roots you may try to argue that there are no more roots.

One way to do this is study the function $f(x)=(57-x)^{1/4}+(x+40)^{1/4}$.

Now, 
we can calculate $$f''(x)= \dfrac{3}{16} \left (-\dfrac{1}{(57 - x)^{7/4}} - \dfrac{1}{(40 + x)^{7/4}} \right )<0.$$

Therefore $f$ cannot have three roots in $(-40,57)$, since that would give two roots for $f'$ contradicting the fact that $f'$ is decreasing.